# Routes in nodeJs + express

Tags: node.js, express

In the nodejs+express application can we have different routes files and include them into a single file. Like as below.

[image]

in hotel.routes.js I have few routes like

```
    const express = require("express");
    const hotelsCtrl = require("../controllers/hotels.controller");
    const router = express.Router();

    router
        .route("/")
        .get(hotelsCtrl.getAllHotels);

    module.exports = router;
```

In the review.routes.js I have few routes like

```
        const express = require("express");
        const reviewsCtrl = require("../controllers/reviews.controller");
        const router = express.Router();

        router
            .route("/")
            .get(reviewsCtrl.getAllreviews);

        module.exports = router;
```

Now I wanted to include both hotel.routes.js and review.routes.js in the index file and when the route is "/hotel" it should go to hotel.routes.js and when the route is "/review" it should go to review.routes.js

can someone please help in fixing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 app.use('/hotel', require('./hotel.routes.js'));
 app.use('/review', require('./review.routes.js'));
```

This puts the `hotel.routes.js` exported router on `/hotel` and the `review.routes.js` exported router on `/review`.

It seems like you've a bit over complicated things by using three files in order to set up a single `/hotel` route.

---

You could also just do:

```
const hotelsController = require("../controllers/hotels.controller");

app.get('/hotel', hotelsController.getAllHotels);
```

There's really no need for the separate hotel.routes.js file.

---

Of, alternatively you could put the `/hotel` in the `hotel.routes.js` file like this:

```
const hotelsCtrl = require("../controllers/hotels.controller");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get('/hotel', hotelsCtrl.getAllHotels);

module.exports = router;
```

And, then all you have to do in `index.js` is this:

```
app.use(require('./hotel.routes.js'));
```

Comment: @Sankar - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.